# Google Music Download Limitations

Tags: android, google-play-store, google-play-music

I was looking at [this Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sapien.music.importer) that allows you to listen to your music that's stored on Google Play Music using any Android music player you wish (rather then just Google's Play Music application).

My confusion though was I was under the impression that Google only allows you to download a song 2 times. If that's the case, how can this application work? I just want to make sure before I download the application, it doesn't use up my 2 download quota per song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for that particular app, but in general Google Music provides two different endpoints for clients (music.google.com, their app, etc): one for streaming, and one for downloading. Only the download endpoint will count towards the limit.

So, as long as that app developer used the correct endpoint, there's nothing to worry about.

If you're curious, here are the two calls that gmusicapi uses:

- [streaming](https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API/blob/5d372555cdca424dd01158a968157e74b46d88c8/gmusicapi/protocol/webclient.py#L485)
- [downloading](https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API/blob/5d372555cdca424dd01158a968157e74b46d88c8/gmusicapi/protocol/webclient.py#L454)